# Bluemix Local: How do I add an existing on-prem DB2 database as service?

Tags: database, db2, ibm-cloud

I am using Bluemix Local and have an existing on-premises database (DB2 LUW) that I want to use with a Cloud Foundry application. How can I make that database "testDB" available as a service, so that my app can use the VCAP_SERVICES variable to access that database?

Do I need a custom broker or will an user-provided service do the trick?

`cf cups db2-testdb` only adds a service, but no JDBC properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user-provided service is the right choice to make any existing on-premises database, DB2 in your case, available for a Cloud Foundry app on Bluemix Local (actually any Cloud Foundry instance).

1. Log in to Bluemix/Cloud Foundry
2. Create the user-provided service
3. Bind the service to an app

You can also update the properties of an user-provided service.

To specify properties during creation use:

`cf cups db2-testdb -p '{"jdbcURL" : "jdbc:db2://yourMachine.com:50000/TESTDB"}'`

To later on change properties (update-user-provided-service):

`cf uups db2-testdb -p '{"jdbcURL" : "jdbc:db2://yourMachine2.com:40000/TESTDB02"}'`

To bind the service to an app use either the GUI or the following command:

`cf bind-service yourAppName db2-testdb`

Your app would then be able to find the service via the `VCAP_SERVICES` variable and read out the value for `jdbcURL`. [See this blog entry for details](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/11/02/twelve-factor-app-avoid-configuration-dependencies/).